# Binding an anchor tag data and its href using XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to bind the anchor tag link to my source.

Actual need is I am having XML attributes such as `<btnVal>` and `<Link>`,

Here Button Val holds the value of Learn More that be displayed to us and link is the href on click where the link should go.

But there am facing a problem in binding this both to the same id.

This is what I have tried.

http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/7/

I need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some minor issues `text()` and `#but_val`:

```
var link = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + prevIndex + ")").find("link").text();
$("#but_val").attr('href', link ).fadeIn("slow");
```

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/10/)